# Tweak Fulltext PDO search

Tags: php, mysql, full-text-search

I would like to tweak the results returned by this Fulltext-query:

```
$STH = $DBH->prepare('SELECT *, 
MATCH (title,title_under,subject) AGAINST (:query) AS score 
FROM articles 
WHERE MATCH(title,title_under,subject) AGAINST(:query IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
order by score desc');
```

Is there a way to return the score calculated by mysql so that I can run my own conditions for adding/subtracting points before parsing the results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the "MATCH() AGAINST() AS score" in your SELECT-statement will already do just that, it'll return the score calculated by MySQL.

I notice you executing the FT search IN BOOLEAN MODE in the WHERE-clause, but not in the SELECT however.